# How to change MIUI force dark mode on expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

MIUI devices are set force dark mode settings. I want to change this but expo android settings are not changing. How to change below settings on expo?

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>`

Comment: Is there any update? I found this https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance/issues/60 but no pull request... the setting should be "userInterfaceStyle": "light" but it does not work for me.

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Comment: Same issue, looking for an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#userinterfacestyle) clearly now, you set this property in `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
  }
}
```

And you MUST also install `expo-system-ui` dependency as well, via `npm install expo-system-ui`