# Standalone apk different from Playstore aab: LinearGradient uses wrong colors

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk, android-app-bundle

I have a weird bug. I am developing a React Native app with [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/) for Android. In one component I am using `LinearGradient` ([expo-linear-gradient](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/linear-gradient/)). In *Expo Go* and a standalone *apk* everything looks fine. But when I build the *aab* (`expo build:android -t app-bundle`), upload it to Playstore, then install it from there, the linear gradient looks different.

I am basically defining 2 gradients, and then choose one depending on the theme (light mode or dark mode). I get the theme from [useColorScheme](https://reactnative.dev/docs/usecolorscheme).

```
const LIGHT_TOP_GRAD = [
  "#ffffffFF", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 )
  "#ffffffE6", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.9 )
  "#ffffffB3", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7 )
  "#ffffff80", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 )
];

const DARK_TOP_GRAD = [
  "#000000FF", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1 )
  "#000000E6", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.9 )
  "#000000B3", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.7 )
  "#00000080", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 )
];

// in a component
const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
const darkMode = colorScheme !== "light";

// later in a render
        <LinearGradient
          colors={darkMode ? DARK_TOP_GRAD : LIGHT_TOP_GRAD}
          style={[styles.pickerGradient, { height: gradHeight }]}
```

In *Expo Go* and *apk*:

- `color` and `backgroundColor` settings change depending on `useColorScheme` (ok)
- `LinearGradient` colors change depending on `useColorScheme` (ok)

In *aab*:

- `color` and `backgroundColor` settings change depending on `useColorScheme` (ok)
- `LinearGradient` always uses `LIGHT_BOT_GRAD` independent of `useColorScheme` (?!)

At first I thought it was the way I define colors. So I switched from `rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 )` to `#ffffff80` (Hex). I also thought that maybe I am seeing a default gradient. But if I leave out the colors prop I get errors.

I know this question is very vague.
But do you have an idea what could be the problem here?

Are there certain things to watch out for? I am new to React Native and Expo.

### Edit: Factories

I have now put the gradients into factories. I was worried that maybe something is mutating the arrays.

```
function getTopGrad(dark: boolean) {
  if (dark) {
    return [
      "#000000FF", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1 )
      "#000000E6", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.9 )
      "#000000B3", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.7 )
      "#00000080", // rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 )
    ];
  }
  return [
    "#ffffffFF", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 1 )
    "#ffffffE6", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.9 )
    "#ffffffB3", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7 )
    "#ffffff80", // rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5 )
  ];
}
```

Anyway it doesn't help. It is like alpha is only supported for white.

### Edit: No Hex Codes

I also tried below version where I only supply 2 colors. One is either white or black, the other is transparent. I was hoping that I can resolve this issue by avoiding Hex codes.

```
function getTopGrad(dark: boolean) {
  return [dark ? "black" : "white", "transparent"];
}
```

Anyway it also doesn't work. It always shows the white gradient.

**Edit: It's the dark mode**

I am getting kind of desperate now. I tried to supplement the gradients with .pngs I created. Even those are being converted to a bright color while in dark mode.

- **black** becomes **white**
- **white** stays **white**
- **blue** becomes **purple**
- a really **dark gray** becomes a really **light gray**

It seems the dark mode tries to make everything very bright.
This is all only showing up in the *aab*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to issues with the dark mode on some devices in general:

- [How to change MIUI force dark mode on expo? (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66128823/how-to-change-miui-force-dark-mode-on-expo)
- [How to force APP in light mode (github)](https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-to-force-app-in-light-mode/33038)
- [How can I force light mode on MIUI? (github)](https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance/issues/60)

In my desperation I fell back to some extreme solutions: I noticed that the style *background-color* is not affected by this whole color converion black box. So, I created a gradient by layering multiple divs with partly transparent background colors. This is the component:

```
function StepGradient(props: {
  height: number;
  layerCol: string;
  top: boolean;
}): JSX.Element {
  const n = 20;
  const just = props.top ? "flex-start" : "flex-end";

  let div = <></>;
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    div = (
      <View
        style={[
          styles.gradient,
          { justifyContent: just },
          { backgroundColor: props.layerCol },
          { height: (props.height * i) / n },
        ]}
      >
        {div}
      </View>
    );
  }
  return div;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  gradientWrapper: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
  },
  gradient: {
    width: "100%",
  },
});
```

Then I use it like this:

```
      <View
        pointerEvents="none"
        style={[
          styles.gradientWrapper,
          { height: 200 },
        ]}
      >
        <StepGradient
          height={200}
          top={true}
          layerCol={darkMode ? "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)" : "rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"}
        />
      </View>
```

This is the only way I was able to make it work (after 3 days trial-and-error).